# Update field with data from the same table

Tags: insert-update

I have a table of employees per year, need to replicate most of the employees within the same table just changing the year to which they relate.

Thanks alot.

Mike Teixeira

Comment: What language are you programming in? Do you have any code you've already worked with where specific things aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (<foo..bar>, year) (SELECT <foo..bar>, '2011' FROM EMPLOYEES)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but now I detected that someone who uses the database already copied some of these employees manually, which will cause a problem of primary key duplication...